# is string an array in php

Tags: php

you can do numeric index in string like in array.
ex.

```
$text = "esenihc gnikcuf yloh";
echo $text[0];
echo $text[1];
echo $text[2];
...................
...................
...................
```

But if you put string in print_r() not same will happen like in array and you cant do count() with string.

I read the documentation and it says.
count()
return 1 if not an array in the parameter

print_r() 
if string is in parameter it just prints that string.

this is not the exact word but something like this.

Why both these functions dont treat string same as an array?

So final question is string an array?

Comment: I know that, and thats not my question.

Answer (score 5):

Unlike for example C, PHP has an inbuilt `string` datatype. The `string` datatype allows you array-like access to the single characters in the string but will always be a `string`. So if you pass it to a function that accepts the `mixed`datatype this function will determine the datatype of the passed argument and treat it that way. That is way `print_r()` will print it in the way it was programmed to output strings and not like an array.

If you want a function that works does the same as `count` for arrays have a look at `strlen`.

If you want you can "turn" your string into an array through `str_split`.

Answer (score 2):

A string is an array if you treat it as an array, eg: `echo $text[0]`, but `print_r` *Prints human-readable information about a variable*, so it will output that variable.

It's called [Type Juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)

```
$a    = 'car'; // $a is a string
$a[0] = 'b';   // $a is still a string
echo $a;       // bar
```

To count a string's length use `strlen($string)` then you can for a `for()`

Comment: So your answer is, string is an array. It just that count() and print_r() didnt work with string like in normal array.

Comment: `count()` works only on arrays types, if you treating as an array like `$string[0]` it will show up as array. `print_r` will print that string or array, in this case string. You can use `str_split()` to make it array

Answer (score 1):

no a string is no array

A string is series of characters, where a character is the same as a byte and  An array in PHP is actually an ordered map. A map is a type that associates values to keys.

Comment: @Joe sorry i dont understand please tell more

Comment: the answer above says it array, then you said it is not.

Comment: I was surprised that PHP strings are like C strings (i.e. an array of bytes not Unicode characters) hence the inability to store and manipulate Unicode strings.

Comment: No, your answer is a perfect quote of the documentation. I thought it might be wrong (I assumed PHP could handle Unicode (hence the question mark)) but I never said it was wrong!

Answer (score 0):

simply everything in the sense every variable in PHP is an array.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too late but:

```
<?php
    $text = "esenihc gnikcuf yloh";
    $arrText = explode(" ", $text);

    foreach($arrText as $word) {
        echo $word . "<br>";
    }
?>
```